# PDO, estan estas guias actualizadas?

Tags: mysql

Quisiera aprender el uso de sentencias preparadas y he conseguido en la red estas paginas, estaran actualizadas? , porque he visto que algunas usan MYSQL

http://prash.me/php-pdo-and-prepared-statements

https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: ¿Qué parte es la que te hace dudar de si son correctas o no?

Comment: pues que no conozco bien jejeje y aparte se ve un poco mas complejo las guias de PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las guías están razonablemente actualizadas, y la última de ellas es la documentación oficial de PHP, de manera que es lo más actualizado que puede existir al respecto.

Respecto a tu duda sobre el uso de MySQL, te comento que MySQL es un motor de base de datos. Desde PHP puedes conectarte a ese motor usando las extensiones `mysql`, `mysqli` y [PDO-MySQL](http://php.net/manual/es/ref.pdo-mysql.php). De estas tres, la primera está abandonada, obsoleta, deprecada y desrecomendada, pero no es lo mismo dar por muerta la extensión `mysql` en particular que los conectores al motor MySQL como conjunto.

Comment: entonces me recomiendas empezar por el manual de PHP, aunque me parece que la phpdeilusion esta mas entendible jejeje, y entiendo lo que dices, pense que era que no se mostraria mas mysql en los codigos jejeje.

Comment: Por lo que estuve leyendo, la guía de PHP delusions está bastante bien.  Y sí, tienes razón en que la documentación de PHP no es muy didáctica en muchos casos.